# Using -mutableCopyWithZone: on custom class makes it immutable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, nscopying, nsmutablecopying

I've created a custom class which conforms to `NSCopying` and `NSMutableCopying`.

I've added an implementation for `-copyWithZone:` and `-mutableCopyWithZone:`, but whenever I call `-mutableCopy` on my object and try to call another method, it crashes because some of the ivars have become immutable, even though I call `-mutableCopyWithZone:` on the ivars.

Here's how I'm copying my class:

```
MyObject *flipped = [list mutableCopy];
[MyObject flip:flipped];
```

(the code fails on `+flip:`, because it tries to use `removeObjectAtIndex:` and `addObject:` on a `NSMutableArray` ivar)

Here's how I'm copying the class:

```
- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    id instance = nil;

    if ((instance = [[[self class] alloc] init])) {

        [instance setArray:[self.array mutableCopyWithZone:zone]];
        [instance setObjects:[self.objects mutableCopyWithZone:zone]];

        [instance setItemCount:self.itemCount];

    }

    return instance;

}
```

I'm not sure why it's failing, but I really don't understand why it isn't making `array` and `objects` mutable.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "the code fails on +flip:, because it tries to use removeObjectAtIndex: and addObject: on a NSMutableArray ivar" - is it really an `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Do you have the array or objects properties declared as `copy`?

Comment: It's not an NSMutableArray at runtime, it is an __NSArrayI, but it's defined as an NSMutableArray in the code.

Comment: @JackGreenhill And how the `setArray:` method is defined (i. e. implemented)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My last idea: if the `setArray:` and `setObjects:` methods are actually setters for properties declared as `@property (copy)`, then they'll copy the arrays passed in - and `copy` always returns an immutable object. In this case, the easy way to fix this would be declaring them as `(retain)` instead of `(copy)`.

Comment: Considering this is inside a `copy`, I suggest setting the ivars of the new instance directly instead of using the set accessor.

Comment: @StevenFisher The problem lies way below this: mutable objects should not be used as properties.

Comment: Agreed. I made an assumption, probably unwarranted, that properties were being used here for memory management purposes only.

Comment: @StevenFisher And that would be fine, IMHO. Still in an immutable way only, though.