# Why does a (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray property create NSArrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I made a mistake while creating a TableView `class`, and accidentally kept my `@property` as `copy` when I defined it:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *words;
```

I initialised the array "correctly": (note this is the third attempt, so please ignore the fact that I'm not using mutableCopy and other better ways of doing this)

```
NSArray *fixedWords = @[@"Eeny", @"Meeny", @"Miny", @"Moe", @"Catch", @"A", @"Tiger", @"By", @"His", @"Toe"];
NSMutableArray *mutWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fixedWords];
self.words = mutWords;
```

However when I later came to reorder the array, it crashed on the removeObjectAtIndex line:

```
id object = [self.words objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
NSUInteger from = fromIndexPath.row;
NSUInteger to = toIndexPath.row;
[self.words removeObjectAtIndex:from];
```

With the error message

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Took a lot of digging to figure out that this is because the copy means that assigning the NSMutableArray results in creation of a standard (nonmutable) NSArray.  Can anyone explain why this is the correct behaviour?

Comment: `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *words;` no use of copy, you shuld use retain.

Comment: or strong instead of retain

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using -mutableCopyWithZone: on custom class makes it immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841130/using-mutablecopywithzone-on-custom-class-makes-it-immutable)

Comment: Ha, I came here because I was hoping today there was a way of doing `@property (nonatomic, mutableCopy)`.  Oh well, guess it'll never happen now with the imminent phasing out of Objective-C in favor of swift.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

-copy, as implemented by mutable Cocoa classes, always [returns their immutable counterparts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html).  Thus, when an NSMutableArray is sent -copy, it returns an NSArray containing the same objects.

Because `words` has the memory qualifier `copy`, this line:

```
NSMutableArray *mutWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fixedWords];
self.words = mutWords;
```

Expands out to:

```
NSMutableArray *mutWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fixedWords];
self.words = [mutWords copy];
```

Given that NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, the compiler doesn't complain, and you now have a ticking time bomb on your hands because NSArray does not recognize it's mutable subclass' methods (because it cannot mutate it's contents).

Comment: To be clear: the `copy` happens in the synthesized implementation of the setter, not at the call site.

Comment: @bbum Of course.  This was just for brevity's sake.  I really didn't want to get into what properties actually were for this kind of question :)

Comment: @CodaFi but NSArray is adopted the NSMutableCopying protocol so why it return NSArray instead of NSMutableArray??

Comment: NSMutableCopying merely says that a class responds to `-mutableCopy(WithZone:)`, not that it returns mutable copies of itself *in all cases*.  Protocols in Objective-C have little to do with behavior and implementation and everything to do with response to particular messages.

Comment: @bbum, I think that tthe language clearly misses a keyword 'mutableCopy' for properties to make it possible to specify that one wants the setter to call 'mutableCopy' instead of 'copy'.

Comment: @Kaiserludi We discussed it at great lengths when adding `@property` to the language.  Ultimately, `mutableCopy` proved to be enough of an edge case with enough one-off business logic related to said one-offs that it wasn't deemed worthy of addition.

Answer (score 8):

Properties aren't magical, they're just shorthand.  Declaring a `@property` on your object tells the compiler to create a backing instance variable and accessor methods for it.  The actual generated code depends on the attributes you set on your property.

It's important to remember that setting a property using dot syntax is also shorthand.  When you call…

```
self.words = mutWords;
```

…you're actually invoking the generated accessor method behind the scenes, like this:

```
[self setWords:mutWords];
```

Since you specified the `copy` attribute on your property, you've told the compiler to generate that `-setWords:` accessor method with code that looks something like this:

```
- (void)setWords:(NSMutableArray *)words
{
    _words = [words copy];
}
```

Knowing all that, you can see what's happening: the generated setter method will call `-copy` on the input argument, and assign the result to the backing instance variable.  Because the `-copy` method is always implemented to return a non-mutable object (performing `[aMutableString copy]` will return an NSString, and so on) setting that property will always store a non-mutable copy.